# Trying to call method of object indexed in ArrayList in C#

Tags: c#, object, methods, arraylist

I'm new to C# and I'm writing a program where I have an `ArrayList` *(`unitArray`)* of `Unit` objects and am trying to call a `non-static` method on the object referenced in the `ArrayList`. I try to access the specific object and call it's method but it doesn't work. I'd be grateful for help resolving this issue.

```
Unit.unitArray[selectedUnit].DisplayUnitAttributes()
```

I get the following exception:

```
'object' does not contain a definition for 'DisplayUnitAttributes' and no extension method 'DisplayUnitAttributes' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: Though you've got different answers already, I guess you should concern tha answer by cdiggins, if all the element of your `ArrayList` are of one and the same type, as there is no sense in a more common `ArrayList` then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to cast the object as its type. In place of MyClass below, substitute your actual class type in.

```
(Unit.unitArray[selectedUnit] as MyClass).DisplayUnitAttributes()
```

Comment: Word. My Man! Thanks a bunch. Is this casting something special with ArrayLists? I suspect this is because these could contain objects of different types?

Comment: Or you could cast it as ((MyClass)Unit.unitArray[selectedUnit]).DisplayUnitAttributes(), which would throw an invalid cast exception if the object is the wrong type, instead of the generic exception thrown by null object references.

Comment: @user1676520: correct, the arraylist stores objects. so when you retrieve you have to cast it from an object.

Answer (score 3):

The type of elements extracted from an `ArrayList` are `System.Object` which is the base class of all objects in C#.

You have to cast  element to a derived type to access the methods or better yet use a `System.Generic.List<T>` where T is the type of the elements in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Enumerable.OfType Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) to get the necessary subarray. Something like this:

```
foreach (YourClass obj in Unit.unitArray.OfType<YourClass>())
    obj.DisplayUnitAttributes();
```

Comment: I like this. Never used it before.

Comment: @Valamas In love with it too. It's very useful to filter "common-typed" collections with this. On the contrary, I almost never use Enumerable.Cast<T> method.